# using sendkeys in UFT it rejects the method shown in this site

Tags: vbscript

```
{Set objClick = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
        objClick.SendKeys "{^+N}"
        Set objClick = Nothing}
```

I'm trying to send control shift n

Answer (score 0):

firstly don't need to use capital N. also in case of multiple keys being used, grouping to be done with {} braces.

You can try your function with below:

```
objClick.SendKeys("+^{N}")
```